# UIkit undefined in Vue web component build

Tags: vue.js, uikit, web-component, getuikit

I try to build Vue web-component with UIkit as UI library. After proper build with command:

```
npm run build --  --target wc --inline-vue --name my-element 'src/App.vue'
```

When I'm trying to embed component in other website UIkit styles are displayed properly, but UIkit instance which handles modal, dropdowns is undefined.

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined
```

Here is main.js file where I initialize global UIkit variable.

```
import App from "./App.vue"
import wrap from "@vue/web-component-wrapper"
import Vue from "vue"
import VueFlatPickr from "vue-flatpickr-component"
import uk from "uikit"
import Icons from "uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.js"
import "flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css"

uk.use(Icons)
Vue.config.productionTip = true
Vue.use(VueFlatPickr)
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      get uk() {
        return uk
      },
    }
  },
})

const app = new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
})
app.$mount("#app")

const WrapperElem = wrap(Vue, App)
window.customElements.define("my-element", WrapperElem)
```

And here a little example of code how I use it and where the trouble occurs:

```
this.uk.modal("#delete-dialog").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your question on the discord channel - I do not have a solution for your question BUT i have already successfully used UIkit 3 and Vue 3 in two of my projects with this base, may it helps you:

https://medium.com/@4ravind/uikit-with-vuejs-vue-cli-3-db811e43c46b